# Shareholder in US based company

Tags: shares, ipo

I am completely blind regarding this stocks and shares. So here is my situation. My brother is working in US. He is going to start an IT company there. I will be a partner. He said he will write 20% share of the company in my name. Also he asked to me to do a research on the procedures of having an indian shareholder for a US based company. My concern is, how can he write 20% share of the company in my name? To buy a share of a company, it needs to go public. So how will he write those 20% shares at the beginning itself. Please advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Companies need to go public before you can buy their shares *on a public stock exchange*, but all companies have shares, even if there's only one share. And anyone who owns those shares can give them to whoever they like (there are generally restrictions on selling shares in unlisted companies to unsophisticated investors, but not on giving them away).